# IndexOutOfRange Exception when trying to save() / insert with nHibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have 2 entities that are playing nice together when I am pulling data out of the database, but now that I am trying to save something I am getting a strange error and elimination isn't helping me track down the cause:

[image]

**Booking**

```
public class Booking
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 bookingID { get; set; }
}
```

**Booking Location**

```
public class BookingLocation
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 bookingID { get; set; }
    public virtual Int32 locationID { get; set; } 
    public virtual DateTime startDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime endDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Booking Mapping**

```
public class BookingMap : ClassMap<Booking>
{
    public BookingMap()
    {
        Table("Bookings");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID");
        Map(x => x.bookingID).Column("BookingID");

        HasMany(x => x.BookingLocations)                
           .KeyColumn("BookingID")
          .Not.LazyLoad().Cascade.All(); 
    }
}
```

**BookLocation Mapping**

```
public class BookingLocationMap : ClassMap<BookingLocation>
{
    public BookingLocationMap()
    {
        Table("Bookings_Locations");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID");
        Map(x => x.bookingID).Column("BookingID");

        Map(x => x.locationID).Column("LID");
        Map(x => x.startDateTime).Column("startdatetime");
        Map(x => x.endDateTime).Column("enddatetime");


        References(x => x.Booking)
         .Column("BookingID")
         .Not.LazyLoad().Nullable()
         .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In insertBooking() function objects: booking and bookingLocation are new transient objects?
And Where's property "Booking" in BookingLocation class (BookingLocation.Booking) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to map the same column twice (`BookingId`):

```
Map(x => x.bookingID).Column("BookingID");

References(x => x.Booking)
     .Column("BookingID")
     .Not.LazyLoad().Nullable()
     .Cascade.All();
```

If you need to reference the field `BookingId` you can just use your many to one (`References`) `Booking.BookingId` so your mapping would become:

```
public class BookingLocationMap : ClassMap<BookingLocation>
{
    public BookingLocationMap()
    {
        Table("Bookings_Locations");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID");
        Map(x => x.locationID).Column("LID");
        Map(x => x.startDateTime).Column("startdatetime");
        Map(x => x.endDateTime).Column("enddatetime");

        References(x => x.Booking)
         .Column("BookingID")
         .Not.LazyLoad().Nullable()
         .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

#### Example

I have read only access to my collections so I use the following methods to add and remove items from this collection:

```
    public virtual void AddBookingLocation(BookingLocation bookingLocationToAdd)
    {
        bookingLocationToAdd.Booking = this;
        this.bookingLocations.Add(bookingLocationToAdd);
    }

    public virtual void RemoveBookingLocation(BookingLocation bookingLocationToRemove)
    {
        this.bookingLocations.Remove(bookingLocationToRemove);
    }
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks ever so much!

Comment: this seems to create a dependency between my 2 entities (BookingLocation and Booking). Is that normal? I feel like I should now pass an instance of Booking into the constructor of BookingLocations in order to be able to access Booking.bookingID ?

Comment: Typically with bidirectional relationships like this I have Add and Remove methods in `Booking` that "automatically" set these relationships up so that you don't have to pass a `Booking` into the constructor of the `BookingLocation`

Comment: ok thanks. I have public virtual int bookingID
        {
            get
            {
                return Booking.bookingID;
            }
            set
            {
                Booking.bookingID = bookingID;
            }
        } - now in BookingLocation and I cannot get it to save the same value as Booking.BookingID in BookingLocation.BookingID, it keeps saving Booking.ID (the primary key field), instead. Any idea what I can do about that or why it's happening? Perhaps you could give an example of this Add / Remove methods, as I might be going about this wrongly altogether...